# call multiple url sequentially with php curl

Tags: php, curl

**How to call more than one url in curl using php and must be executed sequentially one after the another..**

**Below is my php code**

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/handle_login.tcl");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "user=admin&pw=admin&submit=Login");            
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   echo "$response";
   curl_close ($ch);


  $ch1= curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/controller.tcl?sid=$response&type=inverter&inverter=318002N463");
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);         
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response1= curl_exec($ch1);
  curl_close ($ch1);


  $ch2= curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/overview.tcl?sid=$response&menuParentId=3");
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);         
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response2= curl_exec($ch2);
  curl_close($ch2);
```

**Only my first curl command is executed remaining is not being executed**

Comment: You can define a function which accepts URL, with this you can prevent rewriting code everytime, or you can use `multi curl ` but make sure it is not sequential

Comment: @SahilGulati..my first request is post and remaining all are get...

Comment: @Pardeep For that you can pass multiple parameter one as URL and other as Method

Comment: @SahilGulati..Can u please share an example so that i can understand more clearly..

Answer (score 1):

For sequential curl request you can define function and use it like this. If you are not concerned about sequential request you can use `multi curl` for that.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$response=curl_request("http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/handle_login.tcl","POST","user=admin&pw=admin&submit=Login");
curl_request("http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/controller.tcl?sid=$response&type=inverter&inverter=318002N463");
curl_request("http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/overview.tcl?sid=$response&menuParentId=3");

function curl_request($url,$method="GET",$postFields="")
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if($method=="POST")
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);       
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    }
    else
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "$response";
    return $response;

}
```

Comment: @Pradeep Can you tell me the issue you are getting? are getting first `$response` correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144994/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-pradeep).