# Append value to the URL Using curl

Tags: php, curl

[call multiple url sequentially with php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149826/call-multiple-url-sequentially-with-php-curl)

this question is also related to my previous post so ive shared the link above...

Now when i tried append the sessionid in my url execute below code..It didnt run properly..so echoed the url and got following output..

```
3.0971635097876E+183.0971635097876E+1
```

So how to append the sid with the url...

Below is how I've tried..

```
 <?php

    $response=3097163509787559940;
    $url1 = 'http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/controller.tcl?sid='+$response+'&type=inverter&inverter=318002N463';
    echo "$url1";
    $url2 = 'http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/overview.tcl?sid='+$response+'&menuParentId=3';
    echo "$url2";
    $nodes = array('$url1', '$url2');
    $node_count = count($nodes);    

    $curl_arr = array();
    $master = curl_multi_init();

    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++){
        $url =$nodes[$i];
        $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
    }

    do {
       curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
     } while($running > 0);

    echo "results: ";
    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++){
        $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
        echo( $i . "\n" . $results . "\n");
    }
    echo 'done';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 3 changes like below:-

```
$url1 = "http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/controller.tcl?sid=$response&type=inverter&inverter=318002N463";

$url2 = "http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/overview.tcl?sid=$response&menuParentId=3";

$nodes = array($url1, $url2);//remove quotes around urls
```

Comment: Thank u mate...just add another line to ur answer need to place the value between quotes...

Comment: @Pradeep  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Strings are concatenated in `PHP` with dot (.)

Replace concatenation character `+` with `.` in both `$url1` and `url2`

```
$url1 = 'http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/controller.tcl?sid='.$response.'&type=inverter&inverter=318002N463';
```

Remove quotes while creating array. When enclosed in single quotes, it will render it as string and not as variable.

```
$nodes = array($url1, $url2);
```